# inline css for html table padding

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I need to style a table within a CMS but whilst a number of other style elements are working, padding isn't.  I'm trying to increase the padding for individual cells but want to avoid having to add this for each one.  Can it be done?

Below is the basis of what I'm using. (border styles don't seem to work either so I've put that directly in the HTML)

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;padding:10px;">
```

and when I inspect the CSS in the browser there is no indication that elements from the stylesheets are conflicting or over-riding this.

I've seen other answers that mention using display:block or border-collapse and although the padding takes effect it is only applied between the inner table and the border.

Is there something I'm missing or is this just a quirk as to how our designers have set up the site?

thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Generally, the table cells take the CSS styles (esp for padding, borders, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to see what you are trying to figure out here.
I've created a codepen with the code you suggested and it works fine.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;padding:10px;"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
```

http://codepen.io/Bertjuhh/pen/wKjvPP

Please give the full code example in a codepen or something, so we can help properly.

Comment: Yeah, it really is as simple as it is which is why I need to double check with someone who may have come across something similar before.

Comment: Can you provide all the CSS from inspect element which is applied to your table?

Answer (score 0):

you can add css with parent directory to overcome unwanted css

exmaple

```
     table.classname tbody tr td{padding:15px;}
```

This will be applied to all the cell no need to write for all the td inline.